# How to ignore column values under a certain threshold when making a chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a column of about 14,000 populated numerical cells, and when graphing this column I would like to ignore all values that are less than 1000. These values are due to error in sensors and show up occasionally throughout the column. I looked up ways to filter the column to do this, but I want to see the values in the column, just not in the graph. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot chart from your data.

First, create a pivot table by using Insert>Pivot Table.

Put your grouping fields on the rows and columns (depending on the chart you want to create) and put your value in the Values area.

Then filter the row or column items using a value filter (use the filter drop-down, then value filters>greater than)

[image]

Now the data are filtered, use Insert>Pivot Chart and create the chart however you like it.

Comment: This still appears to hide the data in the column, pretty much the same things as the Filter command in the Data tab that I was using. Is there a way to keep the values in the columns but just ignore them in my graph?

Comment: Well... it's hiding the data in the pivot table, sure, but the source data remains unfiltered. 

You can create the pivot table and the pivot chart on the same sheet as the source data if you want and you'll see what I mean.