# Exclude data points in an excel graph without deleting them

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel workbook that automatically runs once a week, pulls in raw data using a plug-in, and creates graphs/tables automatically based off of that raw data. I want the graphs to not plot certain points (more specifically, points whose values are greater than 999999 or less than or equal to 0), but I do not want to simply remove those points, because they are reported in a different table elsewhere on the workbook. I also want to avoid what is essentially copying/pasting a whole new table in without those handful of bad values. Does anybody know of an easy way to do this? If necessary, I can add VBA code in, as long as the workbook as a whole stays lightweight.

Comment: Use a pivot chart so you can filter the values without removing rows.

Comment: i.e.
https://superuser.com/questions/1569545/how-to-ignore-column-values-under-a-certain-threshold-when-making-a-chart-in-exc/1569546#1569546

Comment: Don't know how I missed that post when researching for an answer before posting the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The links you have been pointed to show how to filter a pivot chart. But even if you're not using a Pivot chart, you can remove data points from a chart by filtering the data source.

Use any of the filters in Autofilter and in the Chart source settings make sure that under **Hidden and Empty Cells** the option to **Show data in hidden rows and columns** is NOT selected.

Before filter:
[image]

After filter
[image]